# Создание файла со сгенерированным именем

Tags: python

Есть функция отработки нажатия на кнопку

```
def add_module():  
    a=1
    module_name="cfg/"+combo_select_module.get()+"_"+str(a)+".txt"
    path_module_name=os.path.isfile(module_name)
    module_cfg = open(module_name, "w")
```

- **module_name** - задает путь и имя файла
- **path_module_name** - проверяет есть ли такой файл. возвращает логическое значение (`True` или `False`)
- **module_cfg** - создает файл
- **combo_select_module.get()** - получаем значение из выпадающего списка

Это все работает нормально, без ошибок.

Мне  нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку создался файл , например, **файл_1.txt**.
Если нажать еще раз то создался бы файл **файл_2.txt** , при условии что отсутствует **файл_1.txt**
Если нажать еще раз то создался бы файл **файл_3.txt** при условии что нет файлов **файл_1.txt** и **файл_2.txt**
и так далее.

Пробовал через цикл `while`: обернулось все это тем что у меня за секунду создалось 12 с лишним тысяч файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
s=int(open('sh.txt').read())
def add_module(): 
    global s
    test=open('файл_'+str(s)+'.txt', 'w')
    test.close()
    s+=1
    open('sh.txt', 'w').write(str(s))
w=Tk()
Button(w, text='создать файл', command=add_module).pack()
```

[image: Вот фото]

Теперь даже при повторном запуске программы будут создаваться файлы, которых нет в папке (для этого существует файл `sh.txt`. Сначала его нужно создать в папке, где хранится программа, а затем в него нужно вписать значение **1**. Далее его не нужно изменять ни в коем случае!)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы очень мне помогли!

Comment: Не за что))) Рад был помочь